# issue when executing the pgsql complaining about loop

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

```
create or replace function f() RETURNS void AS 

declare
   tableArray text[] := '{"ADDRESS","CONSISTENCY_CHECK","DEPARTMENT_SUPERVISION"}';
   tableName CHARACTER VARYING;
   value INTEGER ;
   
BEGIN
 FOREACH  tableName IN ARRAY tableArray 
 LOOP   
     select user_id from tableName where user_id=2631;
       if found then
         update tableName set user_id=2651 where user_id=2631;
         delete from tableName where user_id=2631;
  END loop;
end;
```

here is the error that I get when trying to execute the pgplsql: `ERROR syntax error at or near "loop"`

Comment: The function body must be a string literal, typically using dollar quoting.

Comment: I'm not seeing a $$ block around function body.

Answer (score 0):

There are more issues:

1. the body of function should be string - you can use apostrophes or more usual and practical $$ custom string separators.
2. the result of `SELECT` should not be lost. The clause `INTO` is missing.
3. table name should not be a variable - variable cannot be used as table name. In this case you need dynamic SQL - `EXECUTE` statement.
4. camel notation for variable names should not be used for SQL language, that is case insensitive

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() 
   RETURNS void AS $$
   DECLARE
     table_array text[] := '{"ADDRESS","CONSISTENCY_CHECK","DEPARTMENT_SUPERVISION"}';
     table_name text;
     value integer ;
     rc integer
   BEGIN
     FOREACH  table_name IN ARRAY table_array 
     LOOP
       EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE user_id = $1', table_name) USING 2631;
       -- variable FOUND cannot be used for dynamic SQL
       GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
       IF rc > 0 THEN
         EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET user_id = $1 WHERE user_id = $2', table_name) USING 2651, 2631;
         EXECUTE format('DELETE %I WHERE user_id = $1', table_name) USING 2631;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```